# Need to Add Date

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf

So I am trying to **add the current date** to a script that generates a PDF when clicking on a button using jspdf and autotable.src.js. I want to add the date right below the title of the document....

```
<script>

  function generate() {
    // header

    var doc = new jsPDF('l', 'pt');

    <?php include 'imgData.php';?>

    doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 40, 20, 60, 60);
       // xy coords width height

    doc.text(107, 58, "Movies");

    // ADD DATE HERE

    var m_names = new Array("January", "February", "March", 
                            "April", "May", "June", "July",
                            "August", "September", 
                            "October", "November", "December");

    var today = new Date();
    var curr_date = today.getDate();
    var curr_month = today.getMonth();
    var curr_year = today.getFullYear();

    today = m_names[curr_month] + " " + curr_date + ", " + curr_year;
    var newdat = today;

    doc.setFontType("italic");
    doc.setFontSize(10);

    doc.text(107, 74, newdat);

    // DATE END

    // data
    var res = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(document.getElementById("movie"));

    // footer
    var totalPagesExp = "{total_pages_count_string}";

    var footer = function (data) {
    var str = "Page " + data.pageCount;

    if (typeof doc.putTotalPages === 'function') {
        str = str + " of " + totalPagesExp + " - The Movie Connection (LTD) ";
    }
    doc.text(str, data.settings.margin.left, doc.internal.pageSize.height - 30);
    };

    // options
     var options = {
      headerStyles: {
        //fillColor: [104, 163, 194],
        valign: 'middle',
        rowHeight: 28,
        fontSize: 11
      },

      bodyStyles: {
        overflow: 'linebreak', // visible, hidden, ellipsize or linebreak
        columnWidth: 300,
        rowHeight: 24
      },

      afterPageContent: footer,

      margin: {
        top: 90
      }
    };

    doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data, options);

    // Total page number plugin only available in jspdf v1.0+
    if (typeof doc.putTotalPages === 'function') {
    doc.putTotalPages(totalPagesExp);
    }

    doc.save("movies.pdf");
};
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can give us more details what your actual problem is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try This :-

```
var today = new Date();
var newdat = "Date Printed : "+ today;
doc.text(107,68,newdat);
```

Comment: This worked great - I added some styling - but accomplished the job